# Counter Cache customizing for zeros and large numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm still learning rails so any help you can provide would be super helpful. I've set a count for my likes on my book app. Thus, every time a user likes a book - the number increases by one or decreases if the unlike it. However, if no one has liked a book yet - a 0 appears. I'd like that to be blank so that only when a user has liked it will the number appear. I've listed all my relevant code below. Thank you so much.

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "book_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  t.integer  "likes_count", default: 0, null: false
end

create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "book_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

**Book.rb**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, :counter_cache => true
  has_many :users, through: :likes
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Likes.rb**

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Likes Count Migration**

```
class AddLikecountsToBook < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :books, :likes_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
  end
end
```

Comment: `if book.likes.any?`

Comment: you can handle large numbers with [`number_to_human(book.likes.size)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

Comment: Max where do you put this in though do you create a new migration for changing the likes count migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With associations in rails you get several interogation methods such as `.any?` and `.none?` which can be used to create conditional expressions.

```
<% if book.likes.any? %>
  <%= number_to_human(book.likes.size) %>
<% end %>

# or
<%= number_to_human(book.likes.size) unless book.likes.none? %>
```

This uses the counter cache as well to avoid n+1 queries.

Comment: Max sir this works amazing thank you so much! A question just for my knowledge is there any drawback in having this in the views as opposed to the controller?

Comment: I don't really see why you would put this in the controller as its a matter of what you want the view to show.

Comment: Got it, its just that i was reading across SO that most logic actions you want to put in controller over views. But, I defer to you max sir

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want your view to display 0 you could add a if statement in your view.

```
<% if @votes == 0 %>
  be the first to rate this book
<% else %>
  <%= @votes %>
<% end %>
```

Or when returning the variable to the view from the controller

```
def
  if @votes == 0
    @votes = ''
  end
end
```